# Python: Numba with threading layer resolution issue

Tags: python, numba, tbb

I'm trying to install Numba, along with tbb (or omb) as a threading layer.  Even though I've installed both tdd and omb and can see them installed in my virtual environment, at runtime (or using the Numba CLI), it can't seem to resolve either of them as it says, "Disabled due to Unknown import problem".  Any tips on how to resolve this?  Thanks!

The output from numba -s

```
System info:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
__Time Stamp__
Report started (local time)                   : 2023-06-03 12:51:22.078030
UTC start time                                : 2023-06-03 16:51:22.078037
Running time (s)                              : 0.936195

__Hardware Information__
Machine                                       : x86_64
CPU Name                                      : skylake
CPU Count                                     : 12
Number of accessible CPUs                     : ?
List of accessible CPUs cores                 : ?
CFS Restrictions (CPUs worth of runtime)      : None

CPU Features                                  : 64bit adx aes avx avx2 bmi bmi2
                                                clflushopt cmov crc32 cx16 cx8
                                                f16c fma fsgsbase fxsr invpcid
                                                lzcnt mmx movbe pclmul popcnt
                                                prfchw rdrnd rdseed rtm sahf sgx
                                                sse sse2 sse3 sse4.1 sse4.2 ssse3
                                                xsave xsavec xsaveopt xsaves

Memory Total (MB)                             : 32768
Memory Available (MB)                         : 13459

__OS Information__
Platform Name                                 : macOS-13.3.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
Platform Release                              : 22.4.0
OS Name                                       : Darwin
OS Version                                    : Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:17 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_X86_64
OS Specific Version                           : 13.3.1   x86_64
Libc Version                                  : ?

__Python Information__
Python Compiler                               : Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Python Implementation                         : CPython
Python Version                                : 3.9.6
Python Locale                                 : en_US.UTF-8

__Numba Toolchain Versions__
Numba Version                                 : 0.57.0
llvmlite Version                              : 0.40.0

__LLVM Information__
LLVM Version                                  : 14.0.6

__CUDA Information__
CUDA Device Initialized                       : False
CUDA Driver Version                           : ?
CUDA Runtime Version                          : ?
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings Available                : ?
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings In Use                   : ?
CUDA Minor Version Compatibility Available    : ?
CUDA Minor Version Compatibility Needed       : ?
CUDA Minor Version Compatibility In Use       : ?
CUDA Detect Output:
None
CUDA Libraries Test Output:
None

__NumPy Information__
NumPy Version                                 : 1.24.3
NumPy Supported SIMD features                 : ('MMX', 'SSE', 'SSE2', 'SSE3', 'SSSE3', 'SSE41', 'POPCNT', 'SSE42', 'AVX', 'F16C', 'FMA3', 'AVX2')
NumPy Supported SIMD dispatch                 : ('SSSE3', 'SSE41', 'POPCNT', 'SSE42', 'AVX', 'F16C', 'FMA3', 'AVX2', 'AVX512F', 'AVX512CD', 'AVX512_KNL', 'AVX512_SKX', 'AVX512_CLX', 'AVX512_CNL', 'AVX512_ICL')
NumPy Supported SIMD baseline                 : ('SSE', 'SSE2', 'SSE3')
NumPy AVX512_SKX support detected             : False

__SVML Information__
SVML State, config.USING_SVML                 : False
SVML Library Loaded                           : False
llvmlite Using SVML Patched LLVM              : True
SVML Operational                              : False

__Threading Layer Information__
TBB Threading Layer Available                 : False
+--> Disabled due to Unknown import problem.
OpenMP Threading Layer Available              : False
+--> Disabled due to Unknown import problem.
Workqueue Threading Layer Available           : True
+-->Workqueue imported successfully.

__Numba Environment Variable Information__
NUMBA_THREADING_LAYER                         : TBB

__Conda Information__
Conda not available.

__Installed Packages__
Package                          Version
-------------------------------- ---------
appnope                          0.1.3
asttokens                        2.2.1
async-timeout                    4.0.2
avro                             1.11.0
azure-core                       1.26.4
azure-functions                  1.8.0
azure-identity                   1.7.1
azure-messaging-webpubsubservice 1.0.1
azure-storage-blob               12.16.0
backcall                         0.2.0
cachetools                       5.3.0
certifi                          2022.12.7
cffi                             1.15.1
charset-normalizer               3.1.0
click                            8.1.3
cloudpickle                      2.2.1
comm                             0.1.3
contourpy                        1.0.7
cryptography                     40.0.2
cycler                           0.11.0
dask                             2023.4.0
dataclasses-json                 0.5.7
debugpy                          1.6.7
decorator                        5.1.1
Deprecated                       1.2.13
executing                        1.2.0
fonttools                        4.39.3
fsspec                           2023.4.0
google-api-core                  2.11.0
google-auth                      2.17.3
googleapis-common-protos         1.59.0
idna                             3.4
importlib-metadata               6.6.0
importlib-resources              5.12.0
ipykernel                        6.22.0
ipython                          8.13.1
isodate                          0.6.1
jedi                             0.18.2
Jinja2                           3.1.2
joblib                           1.2.0
jupyter_client                   8.2.0
jupyter_core                     5.3.0
kiwisolver                       1.4.4
llvmlite                         0.40.0
locket                           1.0.0
MarkupSafe                       2.1.2
marshmallow                      3.19.0
marshmallow-enum                 1.5.1
matplotlib                       3.7.1
matplotlib-inline                0.1.6
metakernel                       0.29.4
msal                             1.22.0
msal-extensions                  0.3.1
msgpack                          1.0.5
msrest                           0.7.1
mypy-extensions                  1.0.0
nest-asyncio                     1.5.6
numba                            0.57.0
numpy                            1.24.3
oauthlib                         3.2.2
oct2py                           5.6.0
octave_kernel                    0.35.1
OMB                              0.1.dev0
opencensus                       0.11.2
opencensus-context               0.1.3
opencensus-ext-azure             1.1.9
packaging                        23.1
pandas                           2.0.1
parso                            0.8.3
partd                            1.4.0
patsy                            0.5.3
pexpect                          4.8.0
pickleshare                      0.7.5
Pillow                           9.5.0
pip                              23.1.2
platformdirs                     3.5.0
portalocker                      2.7.0
prompt-toolkit                   3.0.38
protobuf                         3.19.6
psutil                           5.9.5
psycopg2-binary                  2.9.3
ptyprocess                       0.7.0
pure-eval                        0.2.2
pyasn1                           0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                   0.3.0
pycparser                        2.21
Pygments                         2.15.1
PyJWT                            2.6.0
pyparsing                        3.0.9
python-dateutil                  2.8.2
pytz                             2023.3
PyYAML                           6.0
pyzmq                            25.0.2
redis                            4.2.0
requests                         2.29.0
requests-oauthlib                1.3.1
rsa                              4.9
scikit-learn                     1.1.0
scipy                            1.10.1
setuptools                       58.0.4
six                              1.16.0
sortedcontainers                 2.4.0
stack-data                       0.6.2
statsmodels                      0.13.5
stumpy                           1.11.1
tbb                              2021.9.0
tblib                            1.7.0
threadpoolctl                    3.1.0
toolz                            0.12.0
tornado                          6.3.1
tqdm                             4.65.0
traitlets                        5.9.0
typing_extensions                4.5.0
typing-inspect                   0.8.0
tzdata                           2023.3
urllib3                          1.26.15
wcwidth                          0.2.6
websockets                       10.2
wrapt                            1.15.0
zict                             3.0.0
zipp                             3.15.0

No errors reported.


__Warning log__
Warning (cuda): CUDA driver library cannot be found or no CUDA enabled devices are present.
Exception class: <class 'numba.cuda.cudadrv.error.CudaSupportError'>
Warning: Conda not available.
 Error was [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conda'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem come from  `TBB` and `OMB` lets try to reinstall them

```
pip uninstall tbb omb
pip install tbb omb
```

if that dont fix it, ensure the Python and Numba can find `TBB` and `OMB` with `echo $PATH`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Uninstalling and re-installing didn't fix the issue.  Also, since I am using a venv, packages are automatically installed into the 'site-packages' directory and Python can resolve these.  Even though everything looks to be properly installed with re: to numba, tdd (and omb), somehow numba isn't liking something.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is there for Stock Python but not for Intel Python. Try installing **Intel® Distribution for Python** instead of stock Python which includes optimized deep learning frameworks and high-performing Python libraries like oneTBB (formely known as TBB) and oneMKL (formely known as MKL). This can be downloaded and installed as a standalone package for macOS from the link: [Intel® Distribution for Python](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-for-python.html).

Once installed, run the following command in a macOS terminal to initialize the Intel® oneAPI environment variables and link the libraries:

```
> source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

Refer sample output below:

```html
> ~ % source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh

:: initializing oneAPI environment ...
   -zsh: ZSH_VERSION = 5.8.1
   args: Using "$@" for setvars.sh arguments:
:: dal -- latest
:: intelpython -- latest
:: ipp -- latest
:: mkl -- latest
:: tbb -- latest
:: oneAPI environment initialized ::

> ~ % python -m numba -s | grep "TBB Threading Layer Available"
TBB Threading Layer Available                 : True
```